# vs code not working properly when pressing enter

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vs-code along with vscodevim extension and seeing strange behaviour and I am not sure what's causing that behaviour.

Suppose I have a following code and imagine `_` represents cursor position

```py
sample = {

    "key": "some value",_  #my cursor is at the end of line
    "another_key": some value"
}
```

When I press enter at the end of the line, the comma moves to next line instead of staying on the same line

```py
sample = {

    "key": "some value"
    ,                                #when pressed enter it inserts new line and moves comma to new line
    "another_key": some value"
```

How can prevent this behaviour and make the comma stay at same line.

Here are my keybindings file and vscodevim settings file:

```
// keybindings.json
[
    {
        "key": "\\ a",
        "command": "workbench.view.explorer",
        "when": "!editiorTextFocus",
    }
    ,
]
```

```
//vscodevimsettings.json
{
    "vim.vimrc.path": "filepath",
    "vim.leader": "<space>",
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": [
                "<leader>",
                "a"
            ],
            "commands": [
                "workbench.view.explorer"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "vim.smartRelativeLine": true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## tldr;

For me, the extension `vscode-styled-components` was causing this problem, disabling it solved to me.**

## Original Answer

In general, it's related to some extension you've installed.

I tried to disable each extension to figure out which was causing this error and then I had to uninstall it.

Comment: This works for me too, I have disabled all extensions and then enabled them, this works for me, but I don't know whats actually causing the issue.

Comment: Great tip! For me this was 'vscode-styled-components'

Comment: yes @TomaszJuszczak unfortunately i had this same extension causing this problem :(

Answer (score 4):

One work around is "ctrl + Enter" instead of only pressing enter. Try this

Comment: Yes. It's a quick fix. I have this problem from time to time but it won't last long. So this is a solution that helps.

Comment: Command + Enter for mac

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

In your [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#:%7E:text=Workspace%20settings.json%20location&text=The%20workspace%20settings%20file%20is,inside%20the%20workspace%20configuration%20file.) add

```json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"
```

Or,

```json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "smart"
```

If you want to turn it off ( I don't know why would you do that )

```json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"
```

Reload vscode and you're good to go

## Explanation

**[editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)**

Controls whether suggestions should be accepted on Enter, in addition to Tab. Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines or accepting suggestions.

Comment: This not work for me.

Comment: Please provide more context as to what you did and how big of a project yours is. Does your problem occur in some situations or follow a set pattern.

In the meantime , this might do it for you [@xiaojueguan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7663663/xiaojueguan)
 `Cntrl+Shift+P` and try Reload Window.

Comment: Hi @Lucifer, sorry to be late for replying this. The condition happenes:
1. I start 3 more vscode instance for  different code base
2. I have enabled 55 more plugins
3. coding for some while
>>> try Reload Window.
This can help for few minutes.
I disabled most plugin and the problem has been solved.But i didn't got what plugin or combination of plugins cause the problem. I'll try later when work load got smaller.

Comment: Its basically happens when your vscode runs out of allocated memory and your language server shuts down.

Deleting or removing extensions can help as does reloading the window until the memory is full again.

So , I think its mostly unsolvable from the consumer side, vscode team or a experienced person can help solve this issue.

Comment: Also you can try and increase the intellisense timer so that your computer gets the time it needs to make intellisense guesses.
`"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 1000` should do it.

Comment: @xiaojueguan do let me know what works and what does not work , I'll update the answer accordingly

Comment: Thank @Lucifer for following, i'll try this week.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but on MacOS, thought it might be helpful for you to check https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adammaras.overtype.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest non-debug solution is to click on "Extensions" and reload them one by one.